# How to use a rewriteToken in the batch storage json api?

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to copy a whole mess of files (1000+) between buckets using the GCS [json api batching](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/batch#batch-example-request). We're grouping our files into batches of 100 and then submitting them using the json api endpoint. When we get back the rewriteToken for files that are taking a long time to copy, however, we're not sure how to use it. I can't even get it to work using a simple curl command:

```
curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer "$(gcloud auth print-access-token) \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
https://storage.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/geoff-dev-central/o/sample.bin/rewriteTo/b/geoff-dev-test/o/sample.bin 

{
  "kind": "storage#rewriteResponse",
  "totalBytesRewritten": "1677721600",
  "objectSize": "4328521728",
  "done": false,
  "rewriteToken": "token1"
}

curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer "$(gcloud auth print-access-token) \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
https://storage.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/geoff-dev-central/o/sample.bin/rewriteTo/b/geoff-dev-test/o/sample.bin \
-d '{"rewriteToken": "token1"}'

{
  "kind": "storage#rewriteResponse",
  "totalBytesRewritten": "662700032",
  "objectSize": "4328521728",
  "done": false,
  "rewriteToken": "token2"
}
```

The totalBytesRewritten is going backwards! I have been trying this in many different ways for over a day now, and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

PS I tried looking at the [google api discovery for storage](https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/storage/v1/rest), and it doesn't talk about how to use the batch api. I then tried looking for the batch location referenced in the api discovery for storage, and that link returned a 404 https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/batch/storage/v1/rest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rewrite token needs to be url encoded and then added as a queryparameter. The reason I was getting "invalid argument" is because the rewriteToken being returned contained '/' and '=' characters that were breaking url parsing. Once I started url encoding the rewriteToken, it worked. For example, if the rewriteToken returned is `token/part1&part2%part3`, then the url to call for rewrite would be

```
https://storage.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/geoff-dev-central/o/sample.bin/rewriteTo/b/geoff-dev-test/o/sample.bin?rewriteToken=token%2Fpart1%26part2%25part3
```

Answer (score 1):

In the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/rewrite) of `rewrite` there is "try it now" functionality. It may help you to generate curl request and I tried it to test it. `rewriteToken` seems to be in link of POST command like:

`POST 'https://...<path with rewriteTo>...?rewriteToken=MyRewriteToken...' etc.`

You can use "try it now" to generate your whole curl command.

I hope it will help!